# ngSantize not working correctly with ng-bind-html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngsanitize

ngSantize not working right now, `<ul ng-bind-html="{{group.content}}"></ul>` is blank when there should be content in there. When you open Dynamic Group Header - 2 it should say

Dynamic Group Body - 2

But it's blank. What am I doing wrong here?

Here's a plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/SOFFK6cdianFADhoWoIJ?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-bind-html` expects an expression so this should be

```
<ul ng-bind-html="group.content"></ul>
```

Comment: It works, thank you. What's the difference between an expression, and an expression inside handlebars? And how can one know when to use one or the other?

Comment: The expressions in curly braces are evaluated using [`$interpolate`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interpolate), while normal expressions are evaluated using [`$parse`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse).
As far as I know, there is not any consistent rule, so the only way to know which one to use is to check the documentation for the directive.